# What is the best(recommended): Create a lang file or store the strings in a database?

Tags: php, database, lang

I'm trying to do a multi language site, so I want to know what is the best way to store the strings(text). For now, I am using a file like (lang_en.php) that contains an array with the key and the string ($lang['MENU_SEARCH'] = 'This is going to show up there'). 
Is this the best way to do this? Using a database is better?

Comment: Most large frameworks use a flat file. But it depends on what your usecase is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Best" clearly depends on the situation.

Benefits of using a text file:

- Easier, quicker development.
- No database hits.
- Can be stored and managed through source code control system.
- Text changes can go through standard QA process.
- Common solution in other il8n frameworks.

Drawbacks of using a text file:

- The strings basically become a "software artifact" - only developers can change them, and a simple change requires a software release.
- Hard to apply formatting to the text, no WYSIWYG.

Benefits of using a database:

- Changes can be done through admin interface, so no technical skills required, and no software release.

Drawbacks of database:

- Moderate amount of effort to build simple version.
- Significant amount of work to build sophisticated version (versioning, test/preview mode); rapidly approaches build of Content Management System in scope.
- Can introduce performance hit if you don't get the caching right.

Comment: Thank you, I think for my needs I will use the file

Answer (score 0):

Database is always better option considering the scalability. On top of database you can have redis like caching mechanism which allows search too in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Up to best of my knowledge and exposure. Best thing is to create php files and define constants for each interface and include them where required. I personally don't recommend the database approach as it will increase the database trips

a hint for **cart.php** file as

**/languages/en/cart.php**

where the syntax of file is something like

**define('Title', 'My Shopping Cart');**